# How to specify json response for swagger's @ApiOperation in my Play/Scala project

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger

I am using swagger for documenting my Play-Scala application.

My controller is as below:

```
@Api(value = "/people")
class PersonController {
  import JsonFormats._

  @ApiOperation(response = ?????, responseContainer = "Array", httpMethod = "GET")
  def showPeople(...) = Action {
    // Code here..to get persons of type List[Person]

    val json: JsObject = Json.obj("people" -> persons)
    Ok(json)
  }
}
```

My JsonFormats.scala is as below:

```
object JsonFormats {
  implicit val personFormat = new Format[Person] {
    def writes(person: Person): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "fName" -> person.name.fName,
        "lName" -> person.name.lName,
        "age" -> person.age)

  }
}
```

My model classes are as below

```
case class Person(name: Name, age: String) {
  gender: String
}

case class Name {
  fName: String,
  lName: String,
}
```

**Question**: What to specify at @ApiOperation's response param in my controller, so it displays the json response structure as expected format (as below), in swagger-ui.

```
{ 
    "people":[
                {
                    "fName":"",
                    "lName":"",
                    "age":""
                }
              ]
}
```

Comment: FYI, your json is not valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a sample to do that :

> ```
>    @ApiOperation(
>     value = "Get a content type by its name",
>     notes = "Returns a content type",
>     response = classOf[models.ContentType],
>     httpMethod = "GET"
>   )
>   @ApiResponses(Array(
>     new ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Content Type not found")
>   ))
> ```

In this case, models.ContentType is case class.

Cheers

Comment: My service response is not exactly in the same structure that a model class specifies. It is being modified using JsonFormat just before sending to client.

Comment: Accepting your answer, as I understood that swagger can not predict the response from implicit object. So, the only way is to use a case class or class as response model.

Comment: why I cannot use
@ApiResponses(Array(
    new ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Content Type not found")
  ))